Spam/offensive chat flag bubbles appearing upon opening chat, but there are no flags
These spam/offensive flag bubbles have been appearing upon opening chat a few times to me today, but there aren't any flags, even if I click immediately after I open the page.


This has happened to me three times today, and it hasn't just hit me - at least two other regular chat.SE users have experienced it.
Obviously this is not a critical bug, but it's probably worth bringing attention to.
An issue which seems to be similar happened before in 2019 regarding moderator chat flags. It was resolved without discussion.
Update Oct 5: I just got another one of these false chat-flag bubbles, this time for 8 notifications, rather than the 2 I had been getting consistently before.

Note that the bubble remains (including reappearing after a refresh) despite no additional flags being raised.  See also this previous report describing the same (or at least a similar) issue.

Its happening now, and amusingly, its ALWAYS no more and no less than 2 flags that triggers this.

Also, the one RELIABLE way to deal with this is to reboot

As a go-to solution, I deleted the cache only to see it still appears.

@User1865345 if it's cache, it's a server side cache that only SE staff/devs can access and clear.

@JourneymanGeek I got it again just now, but for 8 flags this time.
